# READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT support in SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: sql-server, snapshot, express-edition

I wonder if SSE 2005 supports the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option. What I found is this article: [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143761%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). It states that SSE 2005 supports Snapshot Isolation Level (Row-level Versioning), but doesn't support Database Snapshot.

Does it mean that `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` is not supported? Or it is about some other database snapshot feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes from that link it supports it. A Database Snapshot is a read only "frozen in time" (when the snapshot was taken) view of data. This is a tool useful in some  recovery, reporting and rollback preparation scenarios.

The isolation levels you are asking about are all covered by the line talking about Snapshot Isolation Level (Row-level Versioning).

I would question what sort of workload you are putting against SQL Server Express that needs a snapshot isolation level as there are other restrictions on SQL Server Express that tend to make it not a great fit for busier, high concurrency apps (Most notably database size and memory restrictions) but this is certainly supported from that edition features matrix you linked.

Comment: There is no big load on DB, we have a lot of locks due to specific design of application. So enabling of row versioning should help. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Cool - then yes this is a good solution for you and it does work.

Comment: Azure uses read committed snapshot by default. I think Microsoft is trying to steer development towards using this feature as a base instead of read committed with locking. In that context, it makes sense to allow developers to use it in SQL Express, regardless of whether or not the instance will be used for production.

Comment: John, development platforms should be configured the same as production otherwise you'll end up with different results than production (for example no locking when locking will happen in production).

Comment: @mrdenny: Yes, obviously. I was commenting on the last paragraph of the answer, specifically `"I would question what sort of workload you are putting against SQL Server Express that needs a snapshot isolation level ..."`. What I meant was that Microsoft is motivated to include this feature in Express.

Comment: Good point @JonSeigel - not quite how I meant it when I typed it. I agree the Snapshot Isolation levels are a good way to think - and agree it is the default in Azure. It sure beats nolock hints everywhere and it is a good place to start if the infrastructure and TempDB are good to go for row versioning. I just tend to see it in the "box" with concurrency caused issues in busier apps (or reporting workloads against prod) and was asking about the use of Express. Looking back I guess I was somehow subconsciously knocking Express an that was wrong :-)

Comment: Mike, please take two "shame on you"'s from petty cash. :)

Comment: You took all the money from petty cash for the swear jar, I thought? :)